# Nokogiri XML parse offset/limit?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have to parse my XML file and import data from it, but the file has about 1.6GB, about 30M lines of XML, that is respresentation of my 400,000 records.

On my production server the script is killed because of memory. Is there an option to specify how many nodes of a given XPath it should open and any offset to that?

My example code:

```
path = '/my/path'
doc = Nokogiri::XML::parse(File.open(path))
doc.xpath('//tblPodmiotOsoba').each do |node|
  my_import_method
end
```

and is there any option like:

```
path = '/my/path'
doc = Nokogiri::XML::parse(File.open(path))
doc.xpath('//tblPodmiotOsoba', start:0 , end: 100).each do |node|
  my_import_method
end
```

or anything? Any ideas would be useful.

Comment: No, you can't do that using a DOM parser like `Nokogiri::XML.parse`. Instead, you need to use a SAX parser. The first reads the entire file into memory, then parses it. Instead, a SAX reads it line-by-line and your code determines what to do when a tag is read. Nokogiri supports that so read through its [SAX documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html).